# How to count time from when user load a page/form until they submit it?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a quiz page with some questions (multiple choice, true-false). In the results after the submit of page i want to show something like this:

```
Started on  Tuesday, 1 January 2013, 04:09 AM
Completed on    Tuesday, 1 January 2013, 04:10 AM
Time taken  47 secs
Grade   7 out of a maximum of 10 (65%)
```

i dont know how to count start time and end time to show the above results and how to count the time from when user's load a page until they submit the form.

i'm new and i need your advise. i dont have problem if the problem solved with php or javascript or jquery

Comment: you can put time when user starts the quiz in $_SESSION variable and when he finishes the quiz calculate time that has passed since he started. Take a look at php date function  - date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: @vodich what if the user opens the same page in two different tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is my solution:

1- user starts the quiz and you put the time in $_SESSION var

```
 $_SESSION['quiztime']=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

2-User finishes the test and you check the time passed (this example is in minutes you don't have to divide it by 60 if you need seconds)

```
 $to_time = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
 $from_time = strtotime($_SESSION['quiztime']);
 echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minutes";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this and the start and end timestamps will be submitted along with the form. You could then do the calculations with PHP.

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");

window.onload = function() {
    var start = document.createElement("input");
        start.type = "hidden";
        start.name = "start";
        start.value = +new Date()/1000; //unix timestamp

    form.appendChild(start);
};

form.onsubmit = function() {
    var stop = document.createElement("input");
        stop.type = "hidden";
        stop.name = "stop";
        stop.value = +new Date()/1000;

    form.appendChild(stop);
};
```

Comment: my form is like this <form name="input" action="play_quiz.php?action=admin_quiz&quiz_id=<?= $quiz_id ?>" method="post"> and submit button <input type="submit" value="Submit"> can you helpo me how to pass this results to php and calculations? an example? i'm new and little confused

Comment: your answer seem very good but i dont undestard very well what to do

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the time started in a cookie or session, and then once they complete it, just subtract that time from the current time -- That's the time taken!

It may look like this:

Quiz page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['startTime'] = time();
// This is where the quiz would be displayed
```

Quiz results page:

```
session_start();
$totalTime = time() - $_SESSION['startTime'];
echo $totalTime;
```

Comment: What if it took, say, 3 seconds to load the results page?

Comment: There's many factors that could contribute to false readings, however a JavaScript based solution could result in even worse readings.

Comment: If a user wants to change it, he's free to, using the JavaScript solution.

Comment: i combine all the answer and maybe i find the solution.. thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

My "bullet-proofer" solution would be to store the start time on the server, (in the session) associated  with a unique id generated per-form and kept in an hidden field.

This way you prevent the user from tampering with it (he might change the unique id, but in that case the form would be invalid) and you don't depend on the client having javascript enabled.

```
<?php
$form_uuid = uniqid();
$_SESSION['quiz_start_time'][$form_uuid] = time();
```

Then, in your form, put something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php print $form_uuid; ?>">
```

And in the form submit handler:

```
<?php
$form_uuid = $_POST['form_id'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['quiz_start_time'][$form_uuid])) {
    // The user is trying to do something nasty (or the session just expired)
    // Return something like a 400 error
}
else {
    $start_time = $_SESSION['quiz_start_time'][$form_uuid];
    // Do other form processing here..
}
```

Comment: how can i combine your answer with vodich answer above?

Comment: What do you mean for "integrate"? They're two different approaches to the same thing, what exactly do you want to add..?

Comment: all is ok now. i solve with your advices the problem. thanx a lot!